# C# program freezes without breakpoints

Tags: c#, breakpoints, freeze

I'm implementing a program which gets text from various sites and checks which ones are most relevant to a query. The problem is that when I have breakpoints in my code it works perfectly well but without it, the program just freezes. Is this a memory issue? What can I do to solve this please?

THanks

Comment: Without any code we can only guess:) one reason might be that your program takes up the CPU time, this often seems like a "freeze".

Comment: Freezes, or crashes?  And what code are you putting a breakpoint in?  This sort of thing is often a threading issue - a breakpoint on a main thread might give a long-running operation (like a download of text from a site) chance to finish, and so the following code only works with the "wait" you get when the breakpoint is set...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it's not the breakpoints that avoids your program from crashing, but the amount of time the application is stopped.
Perhaps inserting some "sleep" will give you some useful insight about whats going on.

This may happen when your program interacts with thrid party libraries that behind the scenes performs asyncronous calls, or mays busy waits.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem. Disabling "Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls" in Options->Debugging->General changed the issue. For me it made it freeze all the time, much easier to debug.